# Vallidate exposed filters in View

Tags: views

I created a view with Search API.Could you please help how to validate exposed filter(Textbox)
with in a view.

I tried using contextual filter it never worked.

Comment: what do you mean by validate? what do you want to check?

Comment: I want to validate if exposed filters has only letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would alter the exposed form and add a validation handler.

If I remember correctly, the form ID is `views_exposed_form`. Just do a check on the view object (which I think is in the `$form_state` variable) to only add the handler to a certain view/view display.